# undefined reference to GUID_DEVINTERFACE_XXX

Tags: c++, guid, msdn

I am trying to use `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK` (or _FLOPPY... etc) in function `SetupDiGetClassDevs`, but g++ still don't build because of an undefined reference.

I have linked to with SetupAPI and incuded nstddstor.h as requiered (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545824%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I saw that including initguid.h may resolve the problem, but it doesn't for me.

Also, when I try affecting a GUID variable as
`GUID g = GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK;`
and if I put my mouse on GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK, eclipse shows me where is it defined (nstddstor.h), but after compiling, it still doesn't work.

Any solutions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have the Windows DDK handy and so I can't verify it but [a user on another forum reports that it works by including `initguid.h` before `ntddstor.h`](http://www.osronline.com/showthread.cfm?link=201981), so the following *might* work:

```
#include <initguid.h>
#include <ntddstor.h>
#include <Setupapi.h>

// Code copied from:
// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551069.aspx
int main(void) {
    HDEVINFO hDevInfo;
    hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_VOLUME,
        NULL, NULL, DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_INTERFACEDEVICE);
}

cl /nologo /W4 /EHsc /MD guid.cpp Setupapi.lib
```